# Dedicated IP Address

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, webserver, static-ip

I find myself in an interesting position.

I am looking to get a dedicated IP address so that I can host my own server, since I am currently paying a healthy chunk of change per month for a VPS that is virtually useless.

The issue is that the two major ISPs in my area only provide static IP addresses to business accounts and in order to get a business account you must have a registered business.

Right now I am looking around for other local ISPs who do provide dedicated IP addresses, but I am wondering if it is possible to use a proxy as a dedicated IP address and whether or not there are any other ways around this?

Comment: I think the solution you are looking for is dynamic DNS.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I do have a free plan with NoIP.com. I've been doing some digging and I'm at the point where I believe my only option will be NoIP.com's Plus plan so that I can use my own personal domain. How do services like NoIP work, though? Do they use proxies or?

Comment: It uses a program or dameon on a PC, (or router if it's supported in the firmware.) This software periodically updates the dynDNS service that you are using to whatever your current assigned ISP IP address is.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart So no other way around this than dynamic DNS service?

Comment: You mean other than a static IP? I never looked into it, dynDNS works very well for me.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart no, i meant other than using a dynamic dns :(

Comment: You only have two options here, a static IP address which you claim is impossible, or a dynamic IP and then use a dynamic DNS service to point a domain name to your dyamically allocated IP address. Be aware that even if you do this, it might not work... Many ISP's these days use Enterprise Grade NAT and the public IP address you use may be shared by dozens or even hundred of people and inbound routing is not possible.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks. i know it works with NoIP at the very least (and I believe dyndns iirc). it's built into the modem interface options

Comment: @acejavelin just double checked. those are actually the only 2 they allow. im baffled why they would allow dynamic DNS while explicitly prohibiting customers from setting up servers on residential plans tho :/

Comment: Fair enough... I just want to be aware of the possibility. Also, although this is a bit off topic, beware of hosting servers on a "consumer" Internet plan that could be considered "non-personal" use. I work for an ISP, like many ISP's we actively monitor traffic and if there is too much traffic, specifically inbound traffic, it often warrants more research and scrutiny as most consumer plans specifically forbidden server hosting in their T&C.

Comment: You can use most Dynamic DNS services even if your router doesn't support it, you just have to install a small application on a computer in the LAN that reports in every so often, usually once every 30 or 60 minutes.

Comment: @acejavelin oh i know for a fact my isp prohibits hosting servers on residential accounts, whcih is what im subscribed too. luckily my website isnt the type that will generate lots of "loitering" on my site. itll simply offer a service, at which point the user wont have to come back but will be notified. at least thats the case for one of the ideas i have for a business idea. what happens when u catch somebody? u from canada by any chance?

Comment: lol... Close to Canada, but in the US. Simple, service is terminated, depending on the amount of traffic it might be immediate or we may give 30 days notice. At that point they can either stop hosting servers or sign up for a commercial account, but most ISP's here don't require you to be a "registered business".  Basically if you continue to violate the T&C of your service agreement, we terminate your service. Granted this is rare, most people who host their own "servers" are pretty mundane, security cameras, personal file or media servers, etc. Those we generally don't mess with.

Comment: @acejavelin makes sense. good to know. thanks for sharing

Comment: Have you checked out https://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_b_mobile&sc_content=aws_free_p_control_q32016&sc_detail=aws%20free&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=214926188777&sc_matchtype=p&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!214926188777!p!!g!!aws%20free&ef_id=WcFGXwAAA6M45QL3:20180622040554:s ?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart i have, but i dont wan spend any more time learning yet another api. plus ive been told it can get quite expensive, especially for what im gon b doing. thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your home connection is fast and reliable enough (big if) you could find a VPN provider to give you a static IP address over a VPN - or even convert your VPS into an OpenVPN server to provide a static IP to your home. Another advantage of using a VPN is it stops your ISP telling you how you can use resources you have paid for (I can rant on about this...)

You could use a reverse proxy to do something similar, but that has quite a few disadvantages compared with a VPN - about the only positive I can think of is increased speed to cached content)

Comment: so it is indeed possible to use a VPN and or a proxy with a dedicated IP to "proxy" your home server? no idea what a reverse proxy is. my internet is decent, usually 100-125 DL and 30-60 UL

Comment: Let me put it this way - I provided it as a commercial service to a handful of people to bypass the local Telco limitations many years ago when I ran an ISP.  A reverse proxy is where the proxy server is associated with the web server rather then the end user.

Comment: Interesting. Using a VPN sounds like something worth looking into, since encrypted incoming traffic may be indistinguishable from, say, incoming data from gaming, right? But how can a VPN give somebody a static IP?

Comment: Simplifying just a bit - A VPN routes (in this case all) traffic to/from your server via itself - so the world sees the data as originating from the VPN. In fact, early VPNs ran over PPP - the same protocol used by ISPs to connect you to the Internet while hiding their internal Network.

Comment: um, can't ISPs still identify the traffic going from your computer to the VPN and vice-versa, the traffic is simply encrypted? similar to a proxy, except a proxy doesn't encrypt the traffic, no?

Comment: All the ISP sees is encrypted packets with a source/destination of your machine and the VPN's IP. (Assuming you route DNS down it as well)let They't see where the traffic is actually going or what it is - they may be able to make guesses based on packet timing and sizes, but that is hard and inconclusive. Proxies are different - they could be encrypted as well but they only handle specific traffic and don't encapsulate it in another protocol. (ie if you are proxying a web server, only web traffic will be routed through the proxy server...

Comment: And you have the added disadvantage of needing a system in place to act on IP address changes - which is almost seamless with a VPN.

Comment: Are there any particular VPNs you would suggest for doing something like this? Is it tricky setting up the VPN on the server?

Comment: I like OpenVPN because it's robust. From the (web) servers POV integrating a VPN is easy - just run the VPN client on the server and make sure it (a) listens on all interfaces and (b) has an appropriate firewall.  I tend to set up my own VPNs so I don't have provider recommendations. All you need is a low end virtual PC running Linux - ideally close to you and with good Internet connection - and run an OpenVPN server.

Comment: it's open source too, isn't it? i'd still need to use a dynamic DNS to deal with the dynamic IP address.

Comment: It is open source. The beauty of the solution is you don't need to use dynamic DNS - the VPN client on the web server  connects OUT to the VPN server, and re-established a connection whenever the IP address changes.

Comment: how would users connect to my server? by using the VPN's server IP address? Or?

Comment: Depends on the VPN  setup- but yes - by using the IP address of the VPN.

Comment: Aren't the IP addresses of the VPN servers shared by everybody using the VPN, though?

Comment: That depends on the VPN setu, but I imagine that would be fairly common. That's why I said "find A VPN provider to give you a static IP address"

Comment: Right, but didn't you suggest OpenVPN? Would OpenVPN  give out static IP addresses or do they sell them??

Comment: OpenVPN is (open source)software. It can be configured multiple ways. I was not referring to it as a VPN provider (I assume there is some confusion and that the company behind it also offers VPN services?)

Comment: So, for clarification, that would not be possible using OpenVPN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79352/discussion-between-davidgo-and-user2230470).